# Assets - Showing a specific folder

Tags: assets

If I had a folder with a series of subfolders that matched the username, could I show those files to that specific user?  Looking to try making a download portal, but the files are not small enough to be uploaded through PHP. Example:

File Manager Settings:

**/home/www/files/**

Assets Folder tag: 
**parent_folder="{filedir_x}"**

But I wanted to show a single folder in the files directory:

**/home/www/files/{username}**

Assets Folder tag: 
**parent_folder="{filedir_x}{username}"**

The entire tag would look like this:

```
{exp:assets:folders parent_folder="{filedir_20}admin" recursive="yes"}
    <h3>{folder_name}</h3>
    <ul>
        {exp:assets:files folder_id="{folder_id}"}
            <li><a href="{url:huge}" target="_blank">{if title != ""}{title}{if:else}{filename}{/if}</a></li>
        {/exp:assets:files}
    </ul>
{/exp:assets:folders}
```

Using just {filedir_x} worked, but adding {filedir_x}{username} did not.  Is it possible without using entries and just the two Assets tags?  And I would assume from previous posts that if it could, it would show all files as a flat list, and not nested within subfolders?

Comment: Blair, I'm curious if you successfully got this working. I'm looking into doing something very similar. 

Also, if you were able to get this up and running can you confirm if the {exp:assets:files} tag output indeed produced a flat list and not nested subfolders. Thanks.

Comment: Posted the answer below, hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blair,

when Expression Engine calls Assets module tags, {username} is still just a string saying "{username}" (see Low's excellent overview for parse order - http://bit.ly/UwfZE2). You'll have to get the username using a different approach - probably by using PHP on Input.

Comment: Or use Mo' Variables to get `{logged_in_username}` as an early parsed variable: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables

Answer (score 1):

(To answer a request on what I did)
I used a list of folder that .load a template of files like so:

URL: site.com/downloads/me/blair
Username is required in the URL so the segment variable can be used to parse early enough. logged_in_username won't work alone.  There are addons to get around this, might do that in the future, but I couldn't find a native EE way.

File Directory:
home

```
- blair
- - Folder 1
- - - file1
- - - file2
- - - file3
- - Folder 2
- - - file4
```

Folders:

```
<ul>
  {exp:assets:folders parent_folder="{filedir_29}{segment_3}" recursive="no"}
  <li>
    <a href="{path='downloads/_assets'}/{folder_id}/{username}">{folder_name}</a>
    {if total_subfolders}
      <ul>
      {subfolders}
      </ul>
    {/if}
  </li>
  {/exp:assets:folders}
</ul>
```

Files:
URL: site.com/downloads/me/1234 (folder id)

```
{exp:assets:files folder_id="{segment_3}"}
    {exp:link_vault:download_link file_path='{server_path}' text="{filename}"}
      {!-- File display stuff --}
      {!-- Ex: --}
      {server_path} - {filename}...etc. 
    {/exp:link_vault:download_link}    
{/exp:assets:files}
```

I also have some protection, such as wrapping it in a {if segment_3 !=""} so it won't show every single folder (kaboom!) and {if segment_3 != logged_in_username}.  We've also added member_group=="1" to that last conditional so we can check other users list of files quickly, and we don't run a public system to worry about security, all campus internal stuff.  Link vault to track downloads and there's another template to post files publicly that does need link limitations & hiding.
[image]